# Django Rest Framework Path working for one link, but not for other with same setup

Tags: javascript, django, vue.js, django-rest-framework, django-filter

I am trying to access my mysql database through the django rest backend. My frontend uses Vue with Axios. More specifically, I have a junction table **TeacherSubjectJunction**, which I want to access through the following path to get all subjects for a **teacherid**.

**app/urls.py**

```
path('teacherssubjects/<int:teacherid>/', TeacherSubjectJunctionList.as_view())
```

**views.py**:

```
class TeacherSubjectJunctionList(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = TeacherSubjectJunction.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TeacherSubjectJunctionDeepSerializer
    filterset_class = TeacherSubjectJunctionFilter
```

**serializer.py:**

```
class TeacherSubjectJunctionDeepSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = TeacherSubjectJunction
        fields = ['teacherid', 'subjectid']
        depth = 3
```

For Filtering i am using the third party library django-filter

**filters.py**

```
class TeacherSubjectJunctionFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = TeacherSubjectJunction
        fields = ['teacherid', 'subjectid']
```

**models.py**

```
class TeacherSubjectJunction(models.Model):
    pk_teachersubject = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    teacherid = models.ForeignKey(Teachers, models.CASCADE, db_column='TeacherID')  
    subjectid = models.ForeignKey(Subjects, models.CASCADE, db_column='SubjectID')

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'teacher_subject_junction'
```

In my Vue file I am trying to access this path with the following code:

```
async getSubjectsforTeacher(teacher){
                await getAPI.get('/teacherssubjects/?teacherid='+teacher)            
                    .then(response =>{
                        this.SubjectsforTeacherData[teacher] = response.data
                        console.log(this.SubjectsforTeacherData)
                    }).catch(error =>{
                        if (error.response){
                            console.log( error.response )
                        }else if(error.request){
                            console.log( error.request )
                        }else if(error.message){
                            console.log( error.message )
                        }
                    })
               }
```

The above setup gives me the following error:

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/teacherssubjects/?teacherid=3 404 (Not Found)
```

Since I am only a few months into drf, I figured that something about my url setup was wrong. But here is where it gets interesting. I have the exact same setup for another junction called **StudentLectureJunction**, as you can see here:

**app/url.py:**

```
path('studentslectures/<int:lectureid>/', StudentLectureJunctionList.as_view())
```

**views.py:**

```
class StudentLectureJunctionList(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = StudentLectureJunction.objects.all()
    serializer_class = StudentLectureJunctionDeepSerializer
    filterset_class = StudentLectureJunctionFilter
```

**serializer.py:**

```
class StudentLectureJunctionDeepSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    
    class Meta:
        model = StudentLectureJunction
        fields = ['lectureid', 'studentid']
        depth = 4
```

**filters.py:**

```
class StudentLectureJunctionFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = StudentLectureJunction
        fields = ['studentid', 'lectureid']
```

**models.py**

```
class TeacherSubjectJunction(models.Model):
    pk_teachersubject = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    teacherid = models.ForeignKey(Teachers, models.CASCADE, db_column='TeacherID')
    subjectid = models.ForeignKey(Subjects, models.CASCADE, db_column='SubjectID')

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'teacher_subject_junction'
```

And in my Vue:

```
async getStudents(u){
                await getAPI.get('/studentslectures/?lectureid='+this.LectureData[u].lectureid)
                        .then(response => {
                            this.studentsForLectureData[this.LectureData[u].lectureid] = response.data
                            this.LectureData[u].studentid = this.studentsForLectureData[this.LectureData[u].lectureid]
                            
                        })
                        .catch(err =>{
                            console.log(err)
                        }) 
                        
            },
```

This one is working just fine and returns me what I want. Can anyone help me out here?

Answer (score 0):

From the response

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/teacherssubjects/?teacherid=3 404 (Not Found)
```

it seems the string ?teacherid=3 is being passed instead of 3 as you expect

Try using backticks in the url string of the get request like this:

```js
async getSubjectsforTeacher(teacher){
                await getAPI.get(`/teacherssubjects/${teacher}/`)            
                    .then(response =>{
                        this.SubjectsforTeacherData[teacher] = response.data
                        console.log(this.SubjectsforTeacherData)
                    }).catch(error =>{
                        if (error.response){
                            console.log( error.response )
                        }else if(error.request){
                            console.log( error.request )
                        }else if(error.message){
                            console.log( error.message )
                        }
                    })
               }
```

Comment: Unfortunately this one got me a not found as well, because it does not seem to convert it: 

GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/teacherssubjects/$%7Bteacher%7D/ 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Never used getAPI before, you may consider using axios or the standard fetch api to send request to your backend!

Comment: Like I said in my question, I am using Axios. getAPI is just the name i gave to axios, like so:  ```import { getAPI } from '../axios-api'```